# 'at' command not working in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, at

When I schedule a task using `at` in **Arch Linux** it doesn't get *executed* when its time to but it does get *removed from the queue*.

Here is an example of me scheduling a task.

```bsh
at now + 2 min
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at Thu Jul  2 15:34:00 2020
at> code
at> google-chrome-stable
at> <EOT>
job 16 at Thu Jul  2 15:34:00 2020
```

I just want to open a few applications with the `at` command.
`code` is the command that opens up Visual Studio Code.
`google-chrome-stable` opens Google Chrome

Please help!!

Comment: Have you checked your logs ? what is the output of `journalctl -t atd` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Arch, so I cannot easily test in Arch; but `at` in my Kubuntu does not retain the value of `DISPLAY`. The commands you want to run need to display windows, right?

In my tests an attempt to schedule just `kate` (GUI text editor) fails. I need to specify `DISPLAY`:

```
at> DISPLAY=:0 kate
at> <EOT>
```

Then it works.

Use the right value (invoking `echo "$DISPLAY"` before you run `at` may be helpful). Note this is a solution for X Window System. I'm not familiar with Wayland.

If you need to run more than one command then remember all input to `at` creates a script for `sh`. Make the first line `export DISPLAY=:0`, like you would do in a script, so the variable affects all lines that follow. Example:

```
at> export DISPLAY=:0
at> code
at> google-chrome-stable
at> <EOT>
```

The following shell function injects the `export DISPLAY=…` line into code piped to the real `at`. It obtains the value from the variable existing in the current shell, so it makes `at` work as if it retained the value of `DISPLAY`.

```
at () { { printf 'export DISPLAY="%s"\n' "$DISPLAY"; cat; } | command at "$@"; }
```

Use it exactly as you would use `at` if the problem didn't exist. Your code from the question body should now work.

Comment: Thanks for telling it works. But is there a way by which I don't have to type DISPLAY=:0 everytime?

Comment: @MayankShigaonker I can imagine a wrapper script (or a shell function) that prepends the right string to each line of its input before piping to `at`. Before we create some hairy contraption, please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) in your question. Using `at` to spawn GUI programs seems strange to me.

Comment: @MayankShigaonker Answer expanded.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I don't fully understand the function so I'm not going to use it. Instead I'm going to learn more and maybe write a similar function.