# Ubuntu: Running a GUI application using the at command

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, at

How can I run an app showing a GUI (e.g. Chrome, Spotify etc.) at a specified time using the `at` command?

Just doing `echo "/path/to/spotify" | at now` doesn't work.

Edit: I also tried `echo "DISPLAY=0: /path/to/spotify" | at now` and `echo "export DISPLAY=0: && /path/to/spotify" | at now` but they didn't work.

Comment: You may need to specify a `DISPLAY=:0` environment variable and perhaps switch the user. But there are utilities to start scripts at specified times from your desktop (`kalarm` for instance).

Comment: I also tried `echo "DISPLAY=0: /path/to/spotify" | at now` and `echo "export DISPLAY=0: && /path/to/spotify" | at now` but they didn't work. Was I doing it right?

Comment: **The common value is `:0`, *not* `0:`.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['at' command not working in arch linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1566231/at-command-not-working-in-arch-linux)

Comment: Yes! Thank you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a `DISPLAY=:0` environment variable.

```
>at 15:35
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> export DISPLAY=:0
at> /usr/bin/chromium-browser http://stackoverflow.com
at> <EOT>
job 8 at Thu Jul  9 15:35:00 2020
```

(`<EOT>` is really Ctrl-D)

Or you can create a file with:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/chromium-browser http://stackoverflow.com
```

And then use:

```
>at 15:50 <at-commands
```

Note: `DISPLAY` is usually `:0` (short for `localhost:0` IIRC). In any case it should be the same value as found in the `DISPLAY` variable in terminals than you run in your GUI.

Comment: Great, thanks! For others reading this - note that in other setups you might want to use `DISPLAY:=1` or another number based on your actual display.

Comment: No, not `:=1`, `DISPLAY=:1`, see augmented answer.